# Best way to get ints from a string with whitespace?

Tags: c++, string, whitespace

I know this is simple, I just can't recall the best way to do this.
I have an input like `"  5 15 "` that defines the x and y of a 2D vector array.
I simply need those two numbers into `int col` and `int row`.

What's the best way to do this? I was attemping stringstreams, but can't figure out the correct code.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it using a `stringstream`:

```
std::string s = " 5 15 ";
std::stringstream ss(s);

int row, column;
ss >> row >> column;

if (!ss)
{
    // Do error handling because the extraction failed
}
```

Comment: @Downvoters:  If there is a technical error in this answer, please let me know; otherwise I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: In this particular case there's something wrong with the downvoters, not with your code.

Comment: yeah i got some downvoters as well, i think nowadays you get for each good answer at least one downvoter

Comment: Maybe they'd prefer you use an istringstream?

Comment: An `istringstream` would probably be "better", but it looks like everyone here's got some anonymous downvotes, myself included. So that's probably not the reason. Annoying; also the main reason I'm glad -5 rep for downvotes didn't get enacted.

Answer (score 16):

The [C++ String Toolkit Library (StrTk)](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html) has the following solution to your problem:

```
int main()
{
   std::string input("5 15");
   int col = 0;
   int row = 0;
   if (strtk::parse(input," ",col,row))
      std::cout << col << "," << row << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "parse error." << std::endl;
   return 0; 
}
```

More examples can be found [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx)

Note: This method is roughly 2-4 times faster than the standard library routines and rougly 120+ times faster than STL based implementations (stringstream, Boost lexical_cast etc) for string to integer conversion - depending on compiler used of course.

Comment: Streams don't belong to that part of the std lib that comes from the STL.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the `stringstream` way:

```
int row, col;
istringstream sstr(" 5 15 ");
if (sstr >> row >> col)
   // use your valid input
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already validated that the input is really in that format, then

```
sscanf(str, "%d %d", &col, &row);
```

Answer (score -1):

I personally prefer the C way, which is to use `sscanf()`:

```
const char* str = " 5 15 ";
int col, row;
sscanf(str, "%d %d", &col, &row); // (should return 2, as two ints were read)
```